# Prevent Postback on ExpandRow of Telerik Grid Client Detail Template

Tags: kendo-grid, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, autopostback

To speed up the page loading I bring all the data for the telerik grid on the parent Read action and apply it to the client detail template but the client expand options always do a POSTBACK when this is called "grid.expandRow(this)". Is there a way to disable the ExpandRow() POSTBACK for MVC?

```
    $(".k-master-row").each(function (index) {
        grid.expandRow(this);
    });
```

```
            .Name("productgrid")
...
            .Read(read => read.Action("loadproducts", "report",
            new { subscriptionId = Model.SubscriptionId,
            institutionId = Model.InstitutionId,
            isSpecialsReport = Model.isSpecialsReport,
            hasPurchasedFee = Model.hasPurchasedFee, Model.ExternalId}
            ).Data("filterProductGrid"))
```

```
<script id="ratetemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<RateShop.Web.Reports.Models.Report.RateReportViewModel>()
            .Name("rates_#=ProductId#") 
..
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Model(m=>m.Id("InstitutionId"))
                .ServerOperation(false)
isSpecialsReport = Model.isSpecialsReport, hasPurchasedFee = Model.hasPurchasedFee }))
            )
            .Events(e => e.DataBound("ratesDataBound"))
```

I have tried using: e.preventDefault(), return false, etc...

But the kendo.js file seems to do a "click()" on the control the first time the ExpandRow() is called.